# ConstraintLayout height with `wrap_content`

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv2"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iv1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv3"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iv2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    />
```

which gives me the following in the layout preview:

[image]

However, I intend for `ConstraintLayout` to be a child of a `RelativeLayout`, with `ConstraintLayout`'s height set to `wrap_content`. But setting `wrap_content` results in the entire `ConstraintLayout` shrinking to 0 in height. How do I make `wrap_content` work?

Comment: how you arranged the ConstraintLayout inside the RelativeLayout ? can you show me the whole source code of it?

Comment: It will be too long to show. I essentially need 3 square images shown horizontally, with their sizes scaling according to device screen dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oké, first of all you probably should not put an ConstraintLayout inside of an RelativeLayout.

Second, you can not "make wrap_content work" if your Constraintlayout has no defined size and its childeren also have no defined size

to make this work you can A: set Constraintlayout height and width to 100dp or match_parent, or B: set the height and width of the childeren of Constraintlayout to 100dp

100dp is an example

Comment: Thanks, this explains why it doesn't work. I ended up going with another layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear Layout and Weights to make it compatible for all screen sizes.

Below is one such sample,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This won't make the buttons square.

Comment: Yes @squeeish, the above code won't make buttons square. I have mentioned it as a sample code. The intention was to convey the usage idea about Weights attribute using Linear Layout. You can use the idea and implement accordingly as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide the screen directly in `ConstraintLayout`. You must need to add Guideline to set max-width for your `ImageView`. You can get more information about `Guideline` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#constrain-to-a-guideline).

BTW, as per your need that you described in comment section you can make your layout with the use of `GuideLine` like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sunriseContainerRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- first box end guide-line -->
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/firstBoxEndGL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

        <!-- second box end guide-line -->
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/secondBoxEndGL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66" />

        <!-- third box end guide-line -->
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/thirdBoxEndGL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.99" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTimeText"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/firstBoxEndGL"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTimeText"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondBoxEndGL"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/firstBoxEndGL"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTimeText"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/thirdBoxEndGL"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/secondBoxEndGL"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```